# Add a calendar event, and then later retrieve and update the event

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Google Calendar has a simple API that allows you to add an event with an `Id` of your own choosing, as long as it meets some criteria. The beauty of this is that if you need to then update that event at a later date, you can just retrieve it by its id, then update it and post it back.. Job done.

I'm looking for a way to do this in Microsoft Graph, for a user's calendar. So far I can't see any obvious way to do this - I can't set the ID, and I can't see any "metadata"-esque fields that I can set and then reference to get that event back at a later date.

The only solution I can think of is to add the event, then store the event ID somewhere locally, so that I can later retrieve that event via its id. But I'd rather not have to store these event ids in my own database.

Any simple solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You most likely want to use [Open Extensions](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/opentypeextension_post_opentypeextension). These are custom properties that get stored with the event in the user's calendar. You can use these extensions to [retrieve `events`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/opentypeextension_get) as well.

The one catch is that you *will* need to create the `event` first; you cannot create an `event` and add an extension in one operation. That said, your "storage" here is simply keeping the results from creating the event in memory so you can issue a second call using the `id` that was returned.

As an aside, it's worth noting that the `id` in Exchange is not safe to store since it can/will change if the `event` is moved. If you choose to store an identifier, you should use the `iCalUId` property. This property is guaranteed to be both unique and static (it's also portable so it is replicated across all the attendee instances as well).

Comment: Thanks for this. I've been playing with Open Extensions, and I've managed to add some to my test calendar event, with some custom data in it. The problem I see now is that I can't filter the events for that custom data - I can only filter for events that have an open extension id of "xxx" and then get them all, and manually check each one. Does that sound right?